# Crystal Report not working in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports-2008

I have a web application developed on `ASP.NET 4.0`, `SQL SERVER 2008` and `Crystal Report 2008`. When running on `VS2010` it works fine but when i deploy it on `IIS 7` reports are not working.

- Application logins successfully.
- Database is Correct.
- Connection on reports are correct.
- I gave full permission to IIS and Windows\Temp folder

I googled it and found many solution but non of them working.

Please tell me the solution. Furthermore the reports are working on IIS6.

The error is in the below image
[image]

Comment: Check the Crystal Report libraries. Remove and add again from project references.

Comment: Did you change any parameter after deploy? Connectionstrings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution*. I was using `ODBC` and it was the problem.
I deleted the connection from the User DNS and created in System DSN.

*I got that a year ago but it is for people who are searching. It might help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running IIS7 with Crystal with no issues.  Out of the blue, certain reports started failing and creating lock files in `c:\windows\temp.`  The only fix, so far for me, was to open each report and perform the following:

> File > Page Setup > Check off the following option "No Printer
>   (optimize for screen display)"

Afterwards I stopped the application pool, cleaned up the `c:\windows\temp` directory and started the application pool again.  All issues have since been resolved.

**This assumes you have a working IIS7 environment to begin with**